# Communicate with AWS IoT device from mobile/web app

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I have developed an electronic device that connects to AWS IoT Core service through MQTT protocol. Now I can connect, publish and subscribe topics.
The device has some inputs (i.e. buttons) and outputs (i.e. relays).

Now I want to develop a mobile or web application to let an authorized user read inputs status and read/write outputs. More than one user could be authorized to control a single device.

What it's not clear to me, but I have no knowledge of backend technologies, is how to manage users, i.e. mobile/web app.

One strategy is to create a new Thing for each User, with its own certificate. The web/mobile app uses MQTT protocol as the electronic device. Topics can be used as a chat channel: the user asks for inputs status and the device answers with updated status.

Another strategy could be to create a HTTP API (maybe with AWS Gateway API) that web/mobile apps use. The API is programmed to publish and subscribe topics. The user should have a IAM access.

I know I could user Device Shadow, but I don't think it's a good soltion in my use case. The status of inputs can change frequently (maybe 1000 times a day), but the user wants to retrieve the status through the mobile/web app only sometimes (one a day or less frequently). It's seems it's useless to send so many messages to keep the shadow updated.

Comment: You can use the aws-amplify framework to connect your frontend (for example angular or react) with backend. You would set up a cognito user pool in the aws console. And in your frontend code you would then use Amplify Auth to sign in, and Amplify PubSub to communicate with your MQTT messages. This will get liveupdates for your MQTT messages. If you want to retrieve messages that happend when you wasn't logged inn, you can save all mqtt messages in a dynamodb table and then retrieve them with lambda and api gateqway

Answer (score 0):

you can use to connect your WebApp with AWS IoT via MQTT(publish and subscribe methods are also available in the system).

[Front end library documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer the link and see if this solves your problem https://medium.com/@serverlessguru/serverless-real-time-reactjs-app-aws-iot-mqtt-17d023954045.